# cucumber undefined scenarios with Playwright

Tags: selenium, cucumber, undefined

I attempted to install this project https://github.com/Tallyb/cucumber-playwright on my computer, but I fixed all of the configuration issues but did not resolve the undefined issue because this project does not use glue, so how can I resolve this issue?
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1snUj.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPmyp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c98St.png)